# 3D plotting in python, intensity and image analysis

Tags: python, image, analysis

I am trying to create an intensity plot in python from an image I took. The image's shape is a two-dimensional array, where each element has a magnitude value corresponding to intensity. I want to plot it to get mountains and valleys in places of high and low intensity (a 3d plot from a 2d array, basically). Most solutions I've looked at do a meshgrid of some x and y arrays, and then have an equation for z, where the meshgrid x and y arrays are used, which makes it easy to use the plot3D command in python. However, I don't think I can decompose my data into this format, nor is there an equation I know of that can get me the z array. Is there a simple function I can use that I haven't seen?

Comment: I don't understand - isn't the intensity array the Z array you want?

Comment: example of the data and what you have tried so far ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example